# check if one string can be converted to another by cyclically rotating it-Solution taking O(n) time but still rejected saying O(n^2) time complexity

Tags: c++, string

There was a question in coding ninjas to check if one string can be converted to another by cyclically rotating it to right.

I have tried the solution and my concept was to concatenate the string to itself and then use the find function to check if the concatenated string has the other string.The time complexity is O(n) for the find function. But the solution is giving tle on the platform saying the code is taking O(n^2). Can someone explain as to why the code is not getting accepted?

Solution:

```
int isCyclicRotation(string &p, string &q) 
{
    if(q.size()!=p.size()){
        return 0;
    }
    string s=p+p;
    int sz=s.size();
    int qz=q.size();
    if(s.find(q)!=string::npos){
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think code ninja is wrong (not that I would trust any competitive coding site anyway).  `s = p+p` is O(n) and so is std::find. So somehow I think code ninja is trying to tell  you it can be done faster and tries to put a fancy name on it. Also note : doing competitive coding is not a good way to learn C++ and/or software engineering (you will mainly just pickup bad habits)

Comment: I am a final year student and I am trying to be better at problem-solving. These days companies look for people who can solve the problem in the most optimized way. So how could I learn that if I do not solve problems like these in the specified constraints?

Comment: @PepijnKramer OP is using `std::string::find` which is not `O(n)`.

Comment: Programmers and wannabe programmers are often socially inept and so become target of scammers. These "coding ninjas" are valuable lesson that all is not gold that shines. You can get far better in thinking about optimal solutions by reading books of Donald Knuth from sixties and seventies than by doing these tasks of competitive coding.

Comment: @Quimby You're right it is std::string::find, and as far as I can see there is no complexity guarantee on std::string::find so it could indeed be anything ;)

Comment: It is true that `s.find(q)` is linear in the length of `s`, if the length of `q` is constant. But the length of `q` isn't constant, it is an input to the function.

Comment: @SleepyTinker I don't know which company you refer to, but no not all companies look for people who can write the fastest algorithm possible. "optimized" doesn't always mean, the fastest code possible. Optimized in my book often means the "most readable and maintainable (unit testable) code that is fast enough".  And this means learning about dependency injection, abstract base classes, using well named variables and short well named functions (good code reads like a recipe or book).

Comment: Certainly! Thank you very much for providing your insights.

Comment: @SleepyTinker Does the [std::boyer_moore_searcher](https://godbolt.org/z/fj4Ys9xWe) get better results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> The time complexity is O(n) for the find function.

This leaves out an important detail. True, for a string of length `n`, the `find` function performs O(n) comparisons (probably – I do not see a complexity guarantee on cppreference.com). However, those are string comparisons. Comparing a string of length `m` to a longer string takes O(m) character comparisons. So O(n) operations, each taking O(m) time. That gives an overall complexity of O(nm), which in your case, where `m` is `n/2`, is O(n<sup>2</sup>).

I'd guess that the edge case that is being checked is something like the strings `"aaaaaaaB"` and `"aaaaaaBa"`. If the second string is the one you concatenate with itself, you look for `"aaaaaaaB"` in `"aaaaaaBaaaaaaaBa"`. The match occurs late in the search, and each search has to check half the original string length, on average. Give a try by hand and see how many character comparisons you do.

Comment: Yep, I do get it now. Thankyou so much.

Answer (score 3):

Naive implementation of std::string::find is indeed `O(n*m)` for searching for a string of length `m` in longer string of length `n`.

I would assume RKP or similar is used in practical implementations but C++ standard does not impose any complexity limits on the implementation.

I think they want you to implement the concatenation you have done but search using Knuth–Morris–Pratt algorithm.

Comment: I had no idea about this algorithm. I will have to learn about this. Nonetheless, thank you.

Comment: Yeah, the algorithm will handle the edge case described by @JaMiT .